# primefaces chart x axis

Tags: jsf, primefaces, highcharts

You can see the problem from [this site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94BXk.png).

Here is the code of my index.html file:

```
<h:head></h:head>     
   <h:form>
      <p:outputLabel value="Primefaces Tutorial"></p:outputLabel>
      <p:chart type="bar" model="#{viewEmployeesManagedBean.barModel}" style="height:500px"  xaxisAngle="90" />
   </h:form>
</html>
```

I create a chart in primefaces java. `xAxis` overlaps. I use `xaxisAngle`. But it seems it makes no difference. How do I fix it?

I want vertical `xAxis` labels. What should I do?

Comment: where in the PrimeFaces docs did you see the `xaxisAngle` attribute being mentioned? You need to do that in the model by specifying it on an axis or via the extender functionality. See the PF docs for the dateAxis as an example, or in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/date.xhtml)

Comment: Just a hint: you're missing <h:body /> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate refers to it doing in the model. You can however also do it in javascript but you need to use the extender functionality. An example of how to use this in this case is

**JavaScript:**

```js
function customExtender() {
 this.cfg.axes = {
  xaxis : {
   renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
   rendererOptions : {
    tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
   },
   tickOptions : {
    formatString : '%b %#d, %H:%M:%S',
    angle : 60
   }
  },
  yaxis : {
   rendererOptions : {
    tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
   },
   tickOptions : {
    fontSize : '10pt',
    fontFamily : 'Tahoma',
    angle : 30
   }

  }

 };
}
```

**ManagedBean**

```
barModel.setExtender("customExtender");
```