# p:chart zoom with date/time axis shows nothing

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts, jqplot

I have problem to set the zoom on a chart with "date time" axis. I made a simulation comparing the chart of Primefaces with native jqplot. With [jqplot](/questions/tagged/jqplot) native works fine, but with [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces) not.

It seems to me an bug in the calculation of the viewport.

[image: Gif sample]

My JSF page:

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{chartController.model}" id="chart" style="height: 400px" />
```

My managed bean:

```
@Named(value = "chartController")
@ViewScoped
public class ChartController implements Serializable {

    private LineChartModel model;

    public ChartController() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        long[][] lines = {{1334856823000l, 2}, {1334856853000l, 1}, {1334856883000l, 0}, {1334856913000l, 4}, {1334856914000l, 13},
        {1334856943000l, 16}, {1334856973000l, 23}, {1334857003000l, 24}, {1334857033000l, 36}, {1334857063000l, 14}, {1334857093000l, 1}};

        model = new LineChartModel();
        model.setTitle("Primefaces Chart");
        model.setZoom(true);

        LineChartSeries series = new LineChartSeries();

        for (long[] line : lines) {
            series.set(line[0], line[1]);
        }

        DateAxis xaxis = new DateAxis();
        xaxis.setTickFormat("%e/%b %H:%M");
        xaxis.setTickAngle(-30);
        xaxis.setMin(1334856823000l); // if not set this, chart not work
        model.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, xaxis);

        Axis yaxis = new LinearAxis();
        yaxis.setMin(0);
        model.getAxes().put(AxisType.Y, yaxis);

        model.addSeries(series);
    }

    public LineChartModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

}
```

My jqplot native code:

```
<div id="chart" style="height: 400px"></div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

        var lines = [[1334856823000, 2], [1334856853000, 1], [1334856883000, 0], [1334856913000, 4], [1334856914000, 13],
            [1334856943000, 16], [1334856973000, 23], [1334857003000, 24], [1334857033000, 36], [1334857063000, 14], [1334857093000, 1]];

        $.jqplot('chart', [lines], {
            title: "Jqplot Native",
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%e/%b %H:%M',
                        angle: -30
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    min: 0
                }
            },
            cursor: {zoom: true}
        });

    });

</script>
```

The sample project is: https://github.com/douglasjunior/PrimefacesChartZoomTest

- Primefaces: 5.3
- Java EE: 7.0
- GlassFish: 4.1.1

I am researching a few days ago. What am I doing wrong? It's a limitation?

**# UPDATE 2016-08-03:**

Same problem with Primefaces 6.0

**# UPDATE 2016-09-01:**

Based on **@lalitha ramakrishnan** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39264457/2826279) I make it work just including the `jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js` file in xhtml page. For some bug, the Primefaces dont includes this automatically.

But now the lines was always `smooth=true`. I tried configure by `lineSeries.setSmoothLine(false)` and with `extender`, but not worked.

Bug report: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1736

Comment: what does `$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;` do? What if you remove it? Does it work with other chart types?

Comment: That was just a test. The plugins are enabled by default. If I remove this line makes no difference. :(

Comment: This works in the PrimeFaces showcase of 6.0RC4 btw...So it is weird that you state it does not work for you. Sure your are using the same jqplot (e.g. not an old cached one?)

Comment: The showcase is not the same situation. I'm working with date and time. Only date in the format "yyyy-mm-dd" also works well.

Comment: Now here we finally achieved something. Please file a bug with the PrimeFaces github issuelist with these findings. And did you try putting date-time strings in there instead of milliseconds since 1971-01-01?

Comment: Yes, the type of dataset does not change the result. Can be string, long, Date, etc. I will try to report the bug now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify xaxis renderer of your primefaces chart model to be $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer in the javascript.

The following script will be invoked when model's extender property is set to "ext".

> model.setExtender("ext");

```
function ext() { 
//this = chart widget instance 
//this.cfg = options
 this.cfg.axes = {
    xaxis : {
        renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions : {
            formatString : "%b %#d, %H:%M:%S",
            angle : -30
        },
        drawMajorGridlines : false
    },
    yaxis : {
        // Other Options for Y Axis
    }
};
}
```

**See Also**

[How to solve primefaces xAxis overlapping Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936544/primafaces-chart-x-axis/32107715#32107715)

**EDIT:**
You need to include jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js file in your xhtml page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122366/discussion-between-lalitha-ramakrishnan-and-kukeltje).

Comment: Thanks @lalitha ramakrishnan, just including `jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js` the zoom works fine. But now the lines was always `smooth=true`. I tried configure by `series.setSmoothLine(false);` and with `extender`, but not worked. Ps: About the showcase, it use only `date` in axis, the problem is date and time.